Upgrade connection nestjs
Возможно ли средствами NestJS улучшить существующее подключение до подключения на WebSockets без использования переадресации?
Мое приложение при инициации подключения проверяет его валидность, в том случае если подключение валидно предполагается открытие подключения на WebSockets для оптимизации передачи данных.
